# How to disable suspend on Ubuntu 20.04 (systemd) via CLI

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, suspend

I have a laptop that has been installed with ubuntu 20.04 that is being used as a server. Thus I want it to never suspend.

By default it automatically suspends when the lid is closed.

As I can only access it via ssh (and there is no X installed anyway) I need to disable it via the CLI.

Multiple sites suggest using

`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`

This does indeed stop the laptop from suspending while the lid is closed, but results in systemd-logind consuming 100% cpu and continuously logging the following: (multiple times per second)

```
 systemd-logind[514]: Suspending...
 systemd-logind[514]: Unit suspend.target is masked, refusing operation.
 systemd-logind[514]: Failed to execute suspend operation: Permission denied
```

Can anyone tell me how to *properly* disable suspending?

Answer (score 14):

After some more searching, I found the correct answer:

In `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` add the following lines at the bottom:

```
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleHibernateKey=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

and run

`systemctl restart systemd-logind`

to activate the new settings.